# Documentclass Standalone - Outcome with rounded corners

Tags: document-classes, standalone, rounded-corners

Is there an option that the result/ whole document of a standalone file has rounded corners? Just like rounded corners for tikz nodes.

Comment: How do you want these rounded corners to show themselves? E.g. you can just print square white corners on rounded paper, or embed the page in a round-cornered tikz frame. There's really no such thing as a "page with rounded corners" in the abstract sense.

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to produces pdf files where pages are not rectangular and then just simple include them into another latex document. But ok, than I have to make a detour by embdedding my standalone pdf into a round cornered tikz frame.

Comment: Put in another way, a page in a pdf document is always a rectangle.